# Question about setting up Google Analytics with Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-analytics, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question but if theres anyone who would know this is SO. If not, where is the best place to ask this question?

At the bottom of vendor profile when you log in at http://google.com/appsmarketplace, there is a text box for you to insert your GA code.

[image]

Question: what does this do? What kind of stats am I expected to see in Google Analytics? I don't have the luxury of trial and error at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

That field gives you analytics on visits to your Apps Marketplace's product page.  Basically, for security reasons, Google doesn't let you add JavaScript to the page, but they provide the ability to specifically insert Google Analytics tracking.

There's a similar field on code.google.com (Google Code -- for hosting code source), the Chrome Web Store (for web apps), and non-Google sites too... this is standard practice when a website wants to let a third party embed their Google Analytics but doesn't want to give them the ability to add arbitrary JavaScript to the page.